# query parametar in image url

Tags: html

Is there a reason not to do this to force reload image in browser:

```
<img src="http://some.domain.com/the_image.jpg?v=3" />
```

The `?v=3` part, will it break somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly valid and often used together with aggressive client side caching. You could for instance use this URL together and let clients cache the image for a year (as suggested by some RFC as maximum) and change the value as soon as the_image.jpg changes.

Note however, that it's recommended to change the path rather than the query string instead (say /3/the_image.jpg, or the_image-3.jpg). This is mainly due to some faulty implementations (e.g. proxies).